# Cordova WP8 DatePickerPlugin callback not found

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, datepicker, phonegap-plugins, timepicker

I am trying to use [Lee Crossley's WP8 plugin-datetime-picker](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker) for the WP8 flavour of my Cordova app.

I already have iOS, Android and Fireos versions of the app running with their own datepicker plugins, but I'm struggling to get this version to work.

I instantiate the picker like so:

```
<input onclick="doDatePick(this)" readonly name="my-account-dob" id="my-account-dob" value="" class="required" />
```

And try to receive the input like this:

```
function doDatePick(elem) {
    console.log('at doDatePick');
    var onDateSelected = function (date) {
        console.log('inside function');
        alert(new Date(parseInt(date, 10)));
        console.log(new Date(parseInt(date, 10)));
        $(elem).val(DPgetNamedMonthDate(new Date(parseInt(date, 10))));
    }

    datetimepicker.selectDate(onDateSelected);
}
```

The datepicker is displayed, and 'at doDatePick' is logged. But when I confirm the new date in the datepicker, nothing else is logged and Visual Studio reports 'Failed to locate callback for id : DateTimePicker' in its output window. Needless to say, the input box isn't updated with my selected date.

I'm sure the Cordova project is set up correctly; I installed all the plugins I required and did a build before adding any code via Visual Studio. Other third party plugins, such as Chris Brody's SqlLite Plugin work fine.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: There has been a change to Cordova that has caused this, I'm working on a solution and have reported the possible core issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7693

Comment: Datepicker is not being displayed in my case. In logs this is what I found-"'datetimepicker' is undefined file:" Any idea why this error is being logged and my datepicker is not showing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reported [the core issue](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7693) to the Cordova team.

As a temporary workaround, the `platforms\wp8\cordovalib\Commands\BaseCommand.cs` `DetatchHandlers()` method could be replaced with:

```
    public void DetachHandlers()
    {
        this.OnCommandResult = null;
        this.OnCustomScript = null;
        foreach (string callbackId in new List<string>(ResultHandlers.Keys))
        {
            if (!callbackId.ToLower().Contains("datetimepicker"))
            {
                RemoveResultHandler(callbackId);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know it's a hack, but it will get you going. You could alternatively use an older version of Cordova.

Comment: Hack or not, it works perfectly. Thanks very much for the quick resolution!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue on github.

[No result handle issue](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker/issues/2)

Simply I have saved the handler in `selectDate` method of `DateTimePicker.cs` class to read that back on `ResultHandler` dictionary before `DispatchCommandResult`.

```
public event EventHandler<PluginResult> mySavedHandler;
....
public void selectDate(string options)
{
    ....

    if (ResultHandlers.ContainsKey(CurrentCommandCallbackId))
    {
       mySavedHandler = ResultHandlers[CurrentCommandCallbackId];
    }
    ....
}

private void dateTimePickerTask_Completed(object sender, DateTimePickerTask.DateTimeResult e)
{
    ......
    try
    {
      if (!ResultHandlers.ContainsKey(CurrentCommandCallbackId))
      {
          ResultHandlers.Add(CurrentCommandCallbackId, mySavedHandler);
      }
      .....
      DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result + ""));
    }
}
```